# How can I add participants to my calendar event iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calendar, google-calendar-api

all.
I am now working with calendar event at iPhone with Swift.
I want to send an invite to a specific person (ex:person@gmail.com).
There are many way to add event to my calendar, but I can't find the way to add participants(A person will be received my invite).
I have read and found many documents and QA, but I think there is no option to add participants to my calendar event.
Please help me with this issue.
Regards.
Jing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Events: update`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) method to update an event.

In the request body, supply an [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) with the following properties:

> **Required Properties**
>
> - `attendees[].email` - The attendee's email address, if available. This field must be present when adding an attendee. It must be a valid email address as per [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).
>
> **Optional Properties**
>
> - `attendees[]` - The attendees of the event. See the [Events with attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts.html#events_with_attendees) guide for more information on scheduling events with other calendar users.
> - `attendees[].additionalGuests` - Number of additional guests. Optional. The default is 0.
> - `attendees[].displayName` - The attendee's name, if available. Optional.
> - ..........

Additional reference:

- [How to "Add guest" to event via google calendar API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793066/how-to-add-guest-to-event-via-google-calendar-api)
- [Google Calendar API V3 how do I add an attendee to a list of existing attendees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049259/google-calendar-api-v3-how-do-i-add-an-attendee-to-a-list-of-existing-attendees)

Hope this helps!